# Get Configurable product when searching Single product's SKU

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

My store is 90% configurable products, because most of the products have color variation. Is it possible to search for the Single product's SKU or Barcode and magento frontend show the configurable product that contains that Single product?

Example:
iPhone SKU:001
--Gold 001a
--Silver 001b
--Grey 001c

When you search 001a nothing shows up. I want to show the configurable 001 when search any 001a / 001b / 001c

Answer (score 0):

Setup the products visibility:

1. Change all simple product visibility to "Catalog" or "Not visible individually"
2. Make sure all the configurable products' visibility is set to "Catalog/Search" or "Search"

Than

1. Create a product attribute called "child_skus", make it used for quick search and add a comma separated list of the child SKUs.

OR

2. Add the child skus to the configurable product's meta keywords. Make sure the meta_keywords attribute is included in the quick search